# Zeta 3 quick convergent series

Tags: calculus

I found in this paper..
$$\zeta (3)-\left(\frac{16}{3} \sum _{k=0}^1 \frac{\text{csch}\left(\frac{\pi  (2 k+1)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{(2 k+1)^3}-\frac{8}{3} \sum _{k=1}^1 \frac{(-1)^k}{\left(e^{\sqrt{2} \pi  k}+1\right) k^3}\right)=-0.0000446626$$ that give 5 digit for each term it very similar to the Plouffe series. How it is possible calculate the rate of aproximation?

Comment: Could you link the paper you mention?

Comment: http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/inspired2.pdf